# existing xcode/cordova app using phonegap and svn

Tags: macos, svn, xcode

I have no idea what I am asking, let alone if its remotely possible. And if it is, how?

Overall I am trying to get the `www` folder backed up and under version control through the use of SVN, seeing as doing the whole project seems next to impossible due to permissions and paths and whatever else (this project is a collaboration of efforts). However if I Create a SVN repo anywhere it wants to build the initial construct of

main_folder
--trunk
--tags
--branches

which breaks the project from running in simulations and all else. So can anyone give me an idea how I can take at the very least the www folder get it into a repo so I can keep it under version control?

Comment: I am not sure I understand this question.  It's certainly possible to put the entire project under svn, and that's the way most projects do it (whether using svn, git, or something else).  I'm also not sure why you're having problems with the svn repo in simulations, unless you're trying to point the simulations at the repository, rather than a check out working copy.  (svn is not designed to be used as a working copy directly.)

Comment: the fact that the I have to put the www folder in this case where it is initially inside of the trunk folder inside of its main folder so lets say `svn-repo` > `trunk` > `files/folders from www` which throws off the paths the project already use/need